# Android: test suite

Tags: android, unit-testing

I have realize different tests extending the "ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2".
Now, I want to structure my tests: group them and be able to run a subset.

How to do this?
Can I use the TestSuite class?

Any idea?

Regards, 
Alban.

Comment: Did you find any solution for your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the android.test.suitebuilder set of classes, in conjunction with the Smoke, SmallTest, MediumTest, LargeTest and Suppress annotations.  These annotations will allow you to make subsets of tests.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` but I would recommend you to try:

- [Calculon](http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2010/01/10/introducing-calculon-a-java-dsl-for-android-activity-testing/)
- [Positron](http://code.google.com/p/autoandroid/wiki/Positron)